# Vbox container doesn't resize after add function. Extjs4

Tags: extjs4

I'm trying to dynamically add a component to a container with the hbox layout specified
and have that container re-size itself to accommodate the new component. Currently the 
new component is added, but the new and old components are re-sized / or tiled in the
container and the container maintains its size.

Here is a demonstration of the issue I'm having on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrCE9/).

Here is the relevant extjs4 javascript for the demo:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
Ext.create ('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'test',
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'hbox',
            padding : 5,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    id: 'textfieldgroup',
                    flex: 1,
                    height: '100%',
                    border: false,
                    layout: {
                        type: 'vbox',
                    },
                    defaults: {
                        flex: 1,
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            emptyText: 'type here',
                        },
                    ],

                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    flex: .1,
                    text: '+',
                    listeners: {
                        'click' : function () {
                            var textFieldGroup = 
                                Ext.ComponentQuery.query ('#textfieldgroup')[0];
                            var newTextField = Ext.widget ('textfield');
                            textFieldGroup.add (newTextField);
                        },                        
                    }
                }                        
            ]
        }                
    ],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody ()        
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a suitable solution and my reasoning is that you cannot have a vbox dynamically expand within an hbox container. The added benefit is that this method enables you get rid of one level of nesting. Also using the layout property `autoSize: true` enables the vbox container to expand and dynamically re-size itself.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'test',
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    layout: 'vbox',
    items: [
        {
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        flex: 1,
        title: 'Group of fields',
        width: '100%',
        items: [
            {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'hbox',
            width: '100%',
            items: [
                {
                    flex: 1,
                    xtype: 'label',
                    text: 'Fields',
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    flex: 1,
                    text: '+',
                    listeners: {
                        'click': function() {
                            var textFieldGroup =
                            Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#textfieldgroup')[0];
                            var newTextField = Ext.widget('textfield');
                            textFieldGroup.add(newTextField);
                        },
                    }}
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                autoSize: true,
            },
            id: 'textfieldgroup',
            defaults : {
               // flex: 1,
            },
            items : [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    emptyText: 'type here',
                }
            ]                    
        }
        ]}
    ],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
});​
```

​